# Give an example that G has not an element whose order is the least common multiple of m and n.

Tags: abstract-algebra

$G$ is non-abelian , suppose that $G$ has elements of orders
$m$ and $n$, respectively. Then $G$ hasn't an element whose order is the least common multiple of $m$ and $n$.

Now my question is: Give  an example that $G$ hasn't an element whose order is the least common multiple of $m$ and $n$.

My attempts  : I know  that  if $G$ is  abelian then   $G$ has  an element whose order is the least common multiple of $m$ and $n$.  For  example $K_4$.

I  was thinking about non-abelian groups, but  I  was not able to find one ...

Please help me.

Thank  you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The symmetry group on $3$ elements $S_3$ has elements of order $2$ and $3$ but does not have any elements of order $6$.